# How to get value in controller of an bootstrap-multiselect-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-select

I'm new to rails and web. I use the 'bootstrap-multiselect-rails' gem to create a select box and normal inputs.
[image]
When I click the submit button, I don't retrieve the select box informations in the params variable (the inputs are well retrieve).

[image]
This is probably due to the bootstrap-multiselect gem that overrides the behavior of the select box by replacing it with a ul,li system.

`%select#select-type{:multiple => "multiple"}
    - @list_of_type.each do |type|
      %option{value: "#{type.label}"} #{type.label.upcase_first}`

[image]

I have seen answers that explains in retrieving the information in javascript but how to perform treatments on its information in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your select field I cannot see that you assigned a param to it. Usually select  goes like this: `<%= select :input, etc...` where :input is the param you want to save into your model. 
Rails docs give following example:

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { include_blank: true })
```

So the problem is that you did not specify the param. It is also not empty, it is not mentioned at all in your Parameters. Correct?! Than please check the basic docs again on how to create a select field and add the param as requested. Unfortunately, I do not know the exact syntax using your gem. 
I am also not sure about the :multiples=>"multiple". or should it be multiple: true? But I think your version might work with the gem. However, your haml only creates the HTML select with #id and multiple: true. But what you want is something like this

```
<select name="post[category]" id="post_category">
```

So that the param is clear in the select.

Afterwards, when you have saved the param you can use it also in your controller action. 
In conclusion: Add the param to your select field. I don't know how to do this with the gem but you might find some docs may be, or check basic rails docs which might help you out here for sure. Also SO has many questions on select with rails. Good luck!

Comment: You right ! 
I was inspired by the examples of the gem to do the select and so I didn't pay attention to the other parameters. I was on the wrong track.
I add that we must pay attention to the order of the parameters
Select (object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, & block)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the rails code for the multi form? You just need to add a value to each select option which will be stored by rails if you have permitted the params in controller and set up a column for it migrations.

If questions on how to add value to select_tag check out the rails docs. In your html markup i cannot see if the options have value.

Comment: I edited the post to add the code.
I forgot to say that this form aim to refresh a list of articles below, I think there is a relationship with Ajax ... What is the way to recover all these parameters (input and select Box) to use them in a query that will update the list?